# Prototype cells not showing up in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    let transportItems =     ["Bus","Helicopter","Truck","Boat","Bicycle","Motorcycle","Plane","Train","Car","Scooter","Cara van"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return transportItems.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SlopesCell") as? UITableViewCell

    cell?.textLabel?.text = transportItems[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
    }
}
```

Everything is how it should be yet the table view is just showing multiple rows without any text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What do you mean rows without any text? Perhaps are they just extra placeholder type rows at the bottom?

Comment: Did you specify your view controller as the base class for that scene in the storyboard? I'd suggest adding breakpoints or `println` statements in these routines and confirm that they're getting called at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select your tableView controller on the storyboard, click on the third  on the right bar for the identity inspector, at the very top is "Custom Class".

It looks like you forgot to link them up, your class name

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {...}
```

should be entered here, so just type "ViewController" , it should autocomplete. Should be all you need.

Comment: What if you're just using a view controller?

Answer (score 2):

I know its late, but anyone in 2017 still ripping their hair out trying to solve this problem, make sure you are using the correct "identifier" field in the Interface builder to provide your reusable identifier. Interface builder has an "accessibility identifier" and a "reusable identifier" both conveniently labelled in the interface builder as "identifier" which can easily be confused.

See screenshot:
[image]

The Accessibility Identifier has nothing to do with prototype cells - it has to do with providing useful information for users requiring accessibility features (e.g. voice over assistance), see link below for more info:
[Making your iOS app accessible](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the identifier to the cell "SlopesCell" within the table view and also have you  set the class of the table view controller to "ViewController"

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble, I did solve so the solution is as follows
Main Table view cell because it's small we need to enlarge it a bit by writing code

after doing this

Prototypes cell If you have added a photo and this photo is sliding left and right;
Click on the photo you added in Prototypes and select the properties.
content mode / Scale fill

See the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBG1.png)